# Achieving ACID (like) transations in Couchbase

Tags: playframework, transactions, nosql, couchbase

**Context** - I have an application built upon play framework which uses Couchbase as its primary database. Want to achieve some level of ACID compliant transaction capability for multiple documents.
(I'm aware Couchbase 6.5+ already supports multi-document transactions but **my application is on Couchbase 6.0** and it cannot be upgraded at the moment)

**Why** - Observed issues wherein a request fails mid-way through (because of multiple unavoidable reasons) and the documents already modified before the request failed, essentially are corrupted.

**Potential Solutions**

1. Create an interceptor at the DAO layer which will store all the modified documents in the request **context** and commit the documents at the end of the request. This will require some research on the size of the **Play context**, the durability of it, etc.
2. Temporarily store the documents being modified as part of the request to some other store (maybe Redis ? or maybe in a different bucket in Couchbase itself ?) and commit those documents at the end of the request.

I would appreciate inputs on these solutions I've thought of so far.

There also might some other ways to achieve some sort of ACID compliance at the application level for applications using Couchbase. It would be great if someone can help me out here.

Comment: I can almost guarantee that solving whatever problem is preventing the Couchbase upgrade will be easier than developing a robust transactions implementation.

Comment: Not trying to discourage you if it's something you're truly interested in (distributed transactions are a fascinating topic) -- just saying there may be a more efficient way to reach your goal.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few approaches you can try if you absolutely cannot upgrade, but as stated in the comments, an upgrade is going to make many things (not just ACID transactions) so much easier.

Some time ago, I wrote a blog post about one approach: https://blog.couchbase.com/multi-document-transactions-acid-couchbase-2/ called "two-phase commit".

There are 6 steps:

0. Create transaction document
1. Switch to pending
2. Change the documents
3. Switch to committed
4. Remove transaction tags
5. Switch to done

Those are the "happy path" steps. I outline a couple of expections that you'd have to handle, including **Exception during "pending"** and **Exception after transaction "committed"** but there are more exceptions, race conditions, situations that you need to be prepared for.

There's also the [NDescribe project](https://bitbucket.org/ndescribecoreteam/ndescribe/src/master/), which I don't think has been updated in some time, but *might* work for you. Among other features, it includes a transaction implementation.